# Best way to compare two json arrays and make changes to the position

Tags: javascript, json

I have two javascript JSON arrays as follows:

```
this.BicyclePartsOLD;
this.BicyclePartsNEW;
```

So basically both have an attribute "ListOrder". The OLD is ordered by ListOrder from 1 to n items.

The NEW one is modified but had the same records as BicyclePartsOLD, so OLD needs to get updated from NEW. If someone changed `ListOrder` from  1 to 3 in NEW I need to update the OLD list to have that value to 3 and make ListOrder 2 = 1, ListOrder 3 = 2.

I am trying to do it the following way but I am stuck on the best way to set the ListOrder to the new numbers:

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.BicyclePartsOLD.length; i++)
{
     for(var j = 0; j < this.BicyclePartsNEW.length; j++)
     {
          if(this.BicyclePartsOLD[i].PartNumber === this.BicyclePartsNEW[j].PartNumber)
          {
              this.BicyclePartsOLD[i].ListOrder = this.BicyclePartsNEW[j].ListOrder;
              //NOT Sure how to reorder BicyclePartsOLD here, there will be another
              //item with the same ListOrder at this point.  
          }
     }
}
```

Any advices that would lead me into the correct direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking out of the box, instead of having 2 arrays with the same data but totally unrelated in terms of objects, why not create 2 arrays, both containing the same objects? That way, editing an object makes it look like you're editing it in both places.

First of all, [you can have 2 arrays but both point to the same objects](http://jsfiddle.net/wm8Wg/):

```
Array1 -> [{foo:'bar'},{baz:'bam'}]
Array2 -> [{baz:'bam'},{foo:'bar'}]
```

The object with the `foo` in the first array can be the same exact object with the `foo` on the other array (I mean *the same* object instance, not just because they have the same properties). So editing one will basically look as if they changed in both places.

<s>So with that concept, you can just do a [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) on the NEW array to give you a [1-level copy of the array](http://jsfiddle.net/wm8Wg/1/). Basically, it's the same exact items in a different array container. You can then [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the newly sliced array however you want it.</s>

```
this.BicyclePartsOLD = this.BicyclePartsNEW.slice().sort(function(){...});
```

Now to avoid repeatedly slicing like my first solution, I suggest you create both OLD and NEW arrays first. Then when you add an entry, create an object with your data and *push that object into both arrays*, that way both arrays hold the same object, and editing it will reflect on both arrays.

[Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/zTj8F/2/):

```
var OLD = [];
var NEW = [];

// Adding an entry
var newItem = {}
OLD.push(newItem);
NEW.push(newItem);

//Editing that item should reflect on both arrays, since they're the same
OLD[0].someProperty = 'someValue';

console.log(OLD[0].someProperty); // someValue
console.log(NEW[0].someProperty); // someValue


// An item only on OLD
var oldItem = {};
OLD.push(oldItem);

// An item only on OLD
var yetAnotherOldItem = {};
OLD.push(yetAnotherOldItem);

// Let's bring one of those old items to NEW and edit it
NEW.push(OLD[2]);
OLD[2].revived = 'I feel new!';

// Should be in both arrays, but in different indices (since there's the second OLD item)
console.log(OLD[2].revived); // someValue
console.log(NEW[1].revived); // someValue
```

Comment: so would this update the property ListOrder of this.BicyclePartsOLD only and going back to my question, If i find that there is a new value for this.BicyclePartsOLD from NEW, there will be a repeated value with the same ListOrder in BicyclePartsOLD, i need to increase it by 1.

Comment: sounds good. What happens if one array has some of the values of the other array but now all? like var OLD is the biggest set and NEW is a subset of that OLD array? would it still work?

Comment: Like OLD may have 60 items but NEW may have 15 that of course are also in OLD.

Comment: @ergwin Then get those 15 objects on both arrays. That way you retain functionality. [Here's a sample where the first and third OLD items are both arrays, while the second old item remains in OLD.](http://jsfiddle.net/zTj8F/2/)